# Using my ssl certificate to a sub domain

Tags: apache-http-server, certificate, subdomain, google-app-engine

I have a webshop build in Wordpress hosted in Apache. I have created a new version for my front end, build in Google App Engine.

What I want to achieve is my naked domain to point at App Engine and a subdomain called shop.mydomain.com to point in the old Wordpress solution of the shop.

My certificate is for mydomain.com. Is it still going to work for shop.mydomain.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it still going to work for shop.mydomain.com?

No, you'll need either another certificate for `shop.mydomain.com` or a wildcard certificate for `*.mydomain.com` (which is not cheap).

> ## [Wildcard certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate)
>
> A wildcard certificate is a public key certificate which can be used with multiple subdomains of a domain.
>
> [image]